# Erro ORA-01843 ao importar tabela no Sqoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, import

Estou enfrentando um erro do qual não consigo entender a origem.

Anteriormente eu havia importado uma tabela com o mesmo formato de dados, com 54 milhões de linhas para o HDFS do meu *cluster Hadoop*.

Agora eu criei uma `_View_` no meu banco de dados *Oracle* e selecionei uma parcela dos dados da tabela. Agora tem apenas 260k linhas, no entanto agora enfrento esse erro citado mesmo utilizando um comando similar.

***SQOOP***

O erro gerou isso aqui:

> Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue      at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)      at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)       at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)      at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Anteriormente consegui exportar, também com os dados vindos de uma `View`, só que com a tabela completa.

O comando usado foi:
`sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:<meu_host:porta:instancia> --username <user> --password <pass> --table <DB.TABLE> --split-by NUM_LINHA  --m 10 --target-dir  /user/rodrigo/RESUMO_TABELONA 2>&1|tee import_tab_menor.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorreu pela forma como eu criei a *View*, usando uma literal para selecionar um intervalo de datas:

> `DT_F>'02/04/16`

O erro deixou de ocorrer quando eu usei:

> `to_date('02/04/16' , 'dd/mm/yy)`